# .NET Authentication user via cookie and not via header Bearer

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I am looking for a way to authenticate the user via a JWT cookie and not through the authorization header.

I have been looking around but couldn't find an answer I managed to work with.

Currently I am authenticating like this:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
                opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/chat")))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

What is the equivalent to authenticating the same way but with a cookie called `JWT` for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Generate token:

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    public ValuesController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    [Route("GenerateToken")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken()       
    {
         //add claims by yourself...
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
        };
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
                                         _config["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
                                         claims: claims,
                                         expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                                         signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:JwtKey"])),
                                             SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
        var data = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", data, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = true });
        
        return Ok(new { data });                   

    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:JwtIssuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:JwtKey"])),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {                      
                    var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        context.Token = token;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });       
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...           
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();  //the middleware order must like here
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
            
    });
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "jwt": {
    "JwtKey": "JWT_KEYsomethingyouwantwhichissecurewillworkk",
    "JwtIssuer": "https://xxxxxx.com",
    "JwtExpireDays": 15
  }
}
```

After you hit the generate token method, you could set the cookie for the token. Then you can access the method which is declared by authorize attribute:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{  
    [Authorize]       //be sure add this...
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Got in";
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]